# Determining if an ARMA(2,1) is causal and invertible?

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm currently tasked with trying to determine the mean and ACVF of the process, as well as if it is causal and invertible:

$$
X_{t}= 2 + 1.3X_{t−1}−.4X_{t−2}+Z_{t}+Z_{t−1}
$$

I first run into issues when determining causality and invertibility. I am unsure with how to deal with the 2, so whether or not I include the 2 in each of the AR and/or MA polynomials changes my conclusion on whether or not the process is causal and invertible respectively.

For example, If I keep the 2 with the AR polynomial I find:

$$
\phi(z) = -1 -1.3z + .4z^2 = 0
$$

solving for z, I get -.64, and 3.89. Since |-.64| < 1, I would conclude this process is not causal.

However, If I leave the 2 with the MA side, I get the polynomial:

$$
\phi(z) = 1 -1.3z + .4z^2 = 0
$$
again solving for z, this yields 1.25 and 2. Since both of these roots are greater than 1, I would conclude the process is causal.

I run into similar contradiction when I solve the MA polynomial, depending on whether or not I include the 2.

My other issue is with determining the mean of the process. Part of me just wants to say its "2", but I feel like the best way to determine the mean of the process is to convert it to an MA($\infty$), but I don't feel confident in my ability to do that, again because I am unsure about how to deal with the 2.

Any suggestions? I'm stumped.